# How to use psvectorian with pdflatex?

Tags: symbols

I want to use package `psvectorian` with pdflatex.

It does not work out-of-the-box. How to do this?

Answer (score 2):

run it with `pdflatex -shell-escape <file>`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
\usepackage{psvectorian}
\begin{document}

\psvectorian[mirror]{2}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to precompile the symbols with a PS-enabled compilation chain, for instance as follows:

```
% in file ornamentright.tex
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{psvectorian}
\begin{document}
\psvectorian[mirror]{2}
\end{document}
```

Using latexmk:

```
 latexmk -pdfps ornamentright.tex
```

Then you can include `ornamentright.pdf` in say `foo.tex`

```
\includegraphics{ornamentright.pdf}
```

and compile `foo.tex`

```
pdflatex foo.tex
```

Comment: or compile with xelatex

Comment: Then you can use `\includegraphics` to include it in another file, if you like.