# How do I use psvectorian with xelatex

Tags: xetex, psvectorian

I can't successfully compile a simple psvectorian example using xelatex.

I found two answers [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/175769/how-do-you-use-psvectorian) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/253477/how-to-use-psvectorian-with-pdflatex) on SE but neither works for me.  I have tried

1. with TeXShop, with the settings shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mzo9I.png).
2. with the command line, using `xelatex test.tex`.

Below are the output errors from both attempts.

Where have I gone wrong?

The console from TexShop is as follows:

> This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.99992 (TeX Live 2015)
>   (preloaded format=xelatex)  restricted \write18 enabled
>   ....
>   ....
>   (/usr/local/texlive/2015basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/graphics.cfg))))
>   (./test.aux) [1] (./test.aux)
>   xdvipdfmx:fatal: File ended prematurely
>
> Output file removed.  ) Error 256 (driver return code) generating
>   output;
>   file test.pdf may not be valid.

The error from the command line build is as follows:

> /usr/local/texlive/2015basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/graphics.cfg))))
>   (/tmp/test.aux) [1] (/tmp/test.aux)
>   sh: gs: command not found
>   sh: gs:  command not found
>    sh: gs: command not found
>   ...

The MWE I am using is from the first link, and as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{psvectorian,fancyhdr,lipsum,multido}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}% Clear header/footer
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}% No header rule
\fancyhead[C]{\psvectorian[height=.7\baselineskip]{187}}
\fancyfoot[C]{%
  \makebox[0pt]{\thepage}%
  \smash{\raisebox{-\baselineskip}{\makebox[0pt]{\psvectorian[width=\textwidth,height=\baselineskip]{85}}}}}
\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{center}
  \psvectorian[width=.3\textwidth,height=\baselineskip]{47}
\end{center}

\lipsum[2]

\begin{center}
  \quad\multido{\i=102+1}{7}{\psvectorian[height=.8\baselineskip]{\i}\quad}
\end{center}

\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

Comment: I can compile this successfully with `xelatex`

Comment: The error message indicates that `ghostscript` isn't found or not installed at all

Comment: yep, a reinstall of gs worked a charm.