# Missing Arabic character in FreeSerif font / document mixing Korean, English, and Arabic

Tags: xetex, babel, arabic

I've got a document that has English, Arabic, and Korean in it; I'd solved the "English-Korean" combination but anything I tried to do that added Arabic caused a clash with what worked for English and Korean.  Finally [How to add Arabic in-line with English sentence in XeLaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/684654/how-to-add-arabic-in-line-with-english-sentence-in-xelatex) got me a solution which gets me all the Arabic I need *except* for ONE CHARACTER:

> Missing character: There is no ﷺ (U+FDFA) in font FreeSerif/OT:script=arab;lang
> uage=dflt;mapping=tex-text;!

I think the solution is I need to use a different font, but since all my other attempts didn't work precisely because of font reasons, I really don't know what to do.

Here is my mwe:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{kotex} 
\XeTeXcharclass "2026 = 0
\usepackage[bidi=default,english]{babel}
\babelfont[arabic]{rm}{FreeSerif}

\begin{document}

Mahometeu

마호메트

\foreignlanguage{arabic}{ﷺ}

\end{document}
```

Comment: U+FDFA is not so much a character as a special ligature. You can find it in Amiri, IBM Plex Sans Arabic, Noto, and Scheherazade, among other freely available fonts. But your question isn’t answerable in its present state: what exactly did you try to do that caused a clash? Were there error messages? What did they say?

Comment: Which document class are you using? `\documentclass{article}`?

Comment: yes, \documentclass{article} -- sorry, I'm not adept at the formatting of these posts, and I didn't realize that the triple backticks had to be on a line alone before the text to be formatted as code.  That's fixed now.

I gave the text of the error message I received: "Missing character: There is no ﷺ (U+FDFA) in font FreeSerif/OT:script=arab;lang uage=dflt;mapping=tex-text;!"

Comment: That’s not an error: it’s just a warning that the output won’t display the missing glyph, but a PDF is still produced. What’s the clash you mentioned? Does my example work for you?

Comment: The mwe provided was the first attempt I got where there wasn't a conflict between what I needed for Korean and what I needed for Arabic.  The lack of the glyph was the problem: I need that glyph, and this method of generating both Korean and Arabic is the only way I had that _wasn't_ causing a compile error.

Answer (score 1):

At the command line, `albatross ﷺ` will show you which fonts on your computer supply the ligature in question. Amiri is among those in TeX Live.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{kotex}
\XeTeXcharclass "2026 = 0
\usepackage[bidi=default,english]{babel}
\babelfont[arabic]{rm}{Amiri}
\begin{document}
Mahometeu

마호메트

\foreignlanguage{arabic}{ﷺ}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: Alas, I don't have Amiri installed! [And I have been unsuccessful in installing it manually.]  

But the albatross command is super helpful, I'll try one of the fonts I do have, thank you.